# Prove that $1\cdot f(1)+ 2\cdot f(2)+ ...+ n\cdot f(n) \leq n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ where $f(n+1) = f(f(n))+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Consider checking function $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ relationship $f(n+1) = f(f(n))+1$, for any positive integer $n$.
 Prove that $1\cdot f(1)+ 2\cdot f(2)+ ...+ n\cdot f(n) \leq n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106747/show-that-the-following-recurrence-relation-satisfies-the-inequality-displayst

Comment: @Krish that doesn't have a complete solution either.

Comment: We have to show that $f(n)=n$.  
Suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$, then $f(x+1)=f(y+1)$, and so on, so $f(x)$ is periodic.  But every number in the cycle is one more than another number in the cycle - contradiction.  So $f(x)\neq f(y)$ for all $x\neq y$.

Comment: @Michael,  does $f(x) \neq f(y)$ imply $f(x) = x?$

Comment: Sorry, no, what I should have said is: Firstly, what I think has to be shown.  Secondly, here is a fact that is not a solution, perhaps it will help.

Comment: Since it was not clear (to me) in the linked question if $\mathbb{N}^*$ was supposed to include zero, I'd like to know if $\mathbb{N}$ here is supposed to include zero or not?

Answer (score 2):

i am going to try. the defining relation for $f$ gives us the inequality $$nf(n) = n\{f(f(n-1)) + 1\} =n + nf(f(n-1)) \ge n $$ because the range of $f$ consists of positive integers. 
we can use $jf(j) \ge j$ again and again to get
 $$ nf(n) \ge n + nf(f(n-1)) \ge n + nf(n-1) \ge n + n(n-1) = n^2$$

therefore

$$1f(1) + 2f(2) + \cdots + nf(n) \ge 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 $$

${\bf edit}:$ the argument used to establish $f(n) \ge n$ has a flaw but not the conclusion and it can be fixed.

we already have $f(n) \ge 1 \text{ for all } n \ge 1$ by the range of $f$ being positive integers. now using that and $f(n) = f(f(n-1) + 1$ establishes $f(n) \ge 2 \text{ for } n \ge 2 $. now by induction $f(n) \ge n.$

Comment: But this is the opposite of the inequality in the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks for spotting it. i can't find any errors in my reasoning yet. i will keep trying.

Comment: I didn’t see any errors either. I’m beginning to suspect that $f(n)=n$ is actually the only solution, though I can’t prove it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes i checked that too. that is the only linear function that satisfies the functional relation.

Comment: It seems that you say (in your second display equation) that $f(f(n-1))\geq f(n-1)$. I don't see why this follows from $jf(j)\geq j$. Could you explain a bit more in detail for a slow person like me?

Comment: since $j = f(n-1)$ is an integer, i get $f(f(n-1)) \ge f(n-1).$ then use it again on $f(n-1).$ that is $jf(j)$ gets used twice; once with $j = f(n-1)$ then again $j = n-1.$ if this the argument clearer, i will add it to the main body.

Comment: But then it seems (to me) that you use $f(j)\geq j$ rather than $jf(j)\geq j$?

Comment: @mickep, good point. i think the inequality can be recovered. i will edit it.

Comment: @mickep, thanks for spotting the error. i think i have fixed the error. can you please check it out.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, mickep found a flaw in my argument. i think i have fixed it. can you please take a look at it.

Comment: OK, I agree with the update, using induction (was just about to give that argument aswell).

Comment: @mickep, thanks again for pointing out the error gently.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)=f(y)$ then $f(x+1)=f(f(x))+1=f(f(y))+1=f(y+1)$, so $f(n)$ is periodic.  But every number $f(m)$ in the cycle is one more than another number in the cycle.  This is a contradiction, so $f(x)\neq f(y)$ when $x\neq y$.
$f(n+1)=f(f(n))+1>f(f(n))$, so $f(n+1)$ is never the lowest value that $f(x)$ takes.  So $f(1)$ must be the lowest value that $f(x)$ takes.
If $m=f(n)$ is an $f$-value, other than $f(1)$, then $m-1=f(n)-1=f(f(n-1))$ is also an $f$-value.  In the same way, $m-2$ is as well, all the way down to $f(1)$.
So $f(1)+1$ is an $f$-value, call it $f(1)+1=f(k+1)=f(f(k))+1$, so $f(1)=f(f(k))$, and $1=f(k)$.  This is the lowest possible value for $f$, so $k=1$.
So $f(1)=1$, and by induction, $f(n)=n$.

Comment: This is a complete proof, but people seem not to have noticed

Answer (score 1):

Since $1\cdot 1+ 2\cdot 2+ \cdots + n\cdot n = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, it is enough to prove that $f(n)\le n$, for all $n$.

We shall prove that $f(n)\le n$ for all $n$, by full induction.

Assume $f(m)\le m$ for all $m\le n$. Let's prove that $f(n+1) \le n+1$.

Let $m=f(n) \le n$. Then $f(f(n))=f(m) \le m=f(n)$.

So, $f(n+1) = f(f(n))+1 \le f(n)+1 \le n+1$.

All that remains is the base of induction: $f(1)\le 1$.

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: @mickep, the base of induction seems harder.